# Cannot publish test results on TFS builds using MSTest2

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I created a MSTest2 project with Visual Studio 2017, which targets .NET 4.5.1
When I run testcases locally everything works, but when I commit them in my git repository (hosted by TFS servers), TFS will not publish the test results.

I attach part of the unittest logfile (with an error):

```
2018-02-08T12:12:18.4706988Z Attachments:
2018-02-08T12:12:18.4706988Z   <SOME PATH>/<FILENAME>.coverage
2018-02-08T12:12:18.4706988Z 
2018-02-08T12:12:18.4706988Z Total tests: 35. Passed: 35. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2018-02-08T12:12:18.4706988Z Test Run Successful.
2018-02-08T12:12:18.4706988Z Test execution time: 9.6025 Seconds
2018-02-08T12:12:18.7988091Z ##[warning]Failed to publish test results: The given path's format is not supported.
```

I am using VS2017 and the .csproj file contains the following references

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0">
   <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetFramework>net451</TargetFramework>
            <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
   </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="1.1.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="1.1.14" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there anything I can do to make it work on TFS build on servers?
I read MSTest2 does not work well together with TFS. Is there any workaround or any other technology?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MSTest test project using dotnet Core, please **use the dot net core task** with Test verb and not the VSTest task/Run functional test tasks.

Then use publish test results task to publish your test results. Take a look at below sample:

> 1. Remove the **Visual Studio Test** task
> 2. Add the **.NET Core** task (I used version 1.*)
>
>    a. Set the command to **test**
>
>    b. Match the test projects in your repo according to your hierarchy
>      (ex: `test\**\*.csproj`)
>
>    c. Specify the value `--logger:trx` in the Arguments section
> 3. Add the **Publish Test Results** task (I used version 2.*)
>
>    a. Set the **Test Result Format** to **VSTest**
>
>    b. Set the **Test Results Files** to `**\*.trx`
>
>    c. Optionally, update the **Search Folder**; mine was
>      `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\test`
>
>    d. Check the **Merge Test Results** option
>
> *[Soure Link](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/286)*

More details, you could also refer this tutorial-- [TFS 2017 Build- MSTest v2 tests are not recognized](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2017/12/tfs-2017-build-mstest-v2-tests-are-not.html)